# Run time Add/remove/update Arraylist In Java

Tags: java, arraylist, runtime, updates

I am tring to add, update and remove element from arraylist. As I am new in Java or any kind of programming I couldnot figure out the whole solution after googling. I can add element to arrayList. Following is my code:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Scanner;


public class Main {

/**
 * @param args
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    ArrayList<Student> someStudent = new ArrayList<Student>();
    char quit = 'Y';
     int id;
     String name;
     float cgpa;

     while(quit == 'Y'){
         System.out.print("\n ID: ");
         id=scan.nextInt();

         System.out.print("\n Name: ");
         name=scan.next();

         System.out.print("\n CGPA: ");
         cgpa=scan.nextFloat();

         someStudent.add (new Student(id, name, cgpa));
         System.out.print(" Enter Another Record? (Y/N)");
         String word = scan.next();
         word = word.toUpperCase();
         quit= word.charAt(0);
         //scan.close();
     }

     for(Student student:someStudent){
         System.out.println(student.id);
         System.out.println(student.name);
         System.out.println(student.cgpa);
     }
     }
     }
```

Student.java:

```
public class Student {

    public int id;
    public String name;
    public float cgpa;
    //public String address;

    public Student(int id,String name,float cgpa){
        this.id=id;
        this.name=name;
        this.cgpa=cgpa;
    }

}
```

Output of code:

```
ID: 1

 Name: abc

 CGPA: 3.5
 Enter Another Record? (Y/N)y

 ID: 2

 Name: def

 CGPA: 2.6
 Enter Another Record? (Y/N)y

 ID: 3

 Name: xyz

 CGPA: 4.0
 Enter Another Record? (Y/N)n
1
abc
3.5
2
def
2.6
3
xyz
4.0
```

my question is how can i search element from that arraylist and update or remove them.

Comment: Your question is still somewhat unclear. Could you be more specific about what criteria you want to use to search? You could get user input to compare against the fields of each Student object and ask if the user would like to update certain fields (i.e. change cgpa).

Comment: search element based on ID

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try something like this:

```
System.out.print("Select student by ID: ";
int pickID = scan.nextInt();
boolean found = false;
for(Student s : someStudent){
    if(s.id == pickID && !found){
        update(s);
        found = true;
    }
}
if(!found){
    System.out.println("No student with that ID.");
}
```

update method

```
public void update(Student s){
    boolean edit = true;
    while(edit){
        System.out.println(String.format("Select operation:\n1. Change name\n2. Change ID\n3. Change CGPA\n4. Delete\n5. Done"));
        int opt = scan.nextInt();
        switch(opt){
            case 1:
                String newName = scan.next();
                s.setName(newName);
                break;
            case 2:
                int newID = scan.nextInt();
                s.setID(newID);
                break;
            case 3:
                float newCGPA = scan.nextFloat();
                s.setCGPA(newCGPA);
                break;
            case 4:
                for(int i=0;i<someStudent.length();i++){
                    if(someStudent.get(i)==s){
                        someStudent.remove(i);
                    }
                }
                break;
            case 5:
                edit = false;
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

Add methods to Student class

```
public void setID(int id){this.id=id;}
public void setName(String name){this.name=name;}
public void setCGPA(float cgpa){this.cgpa=cgpa;}
```

Answer (score 0):

Depending on what exactly you want to search (I guess names are not unique, IDs are but how about cgpa?) you should use a Map instead list. So you'll be able to find Student based on the unique key in that map.

Comment: Please refer to this link and read about map: http://examples.javacodegeeks.com/java-basics/java-map-example/ lists are not a silver bullet :)